# Esri Geoportal Server on Linux install error?

Tags: installation, linux, esri-geoportal-server

I'm following the [How to Set Up Esri Geoportal Server](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/geoportal-server-setup-on-linux.pdf) on Linux white paper.
Going everything OK until I have to run ./grants_linuxpg.sh (page 10)

`./grants_linuxpg.sh: 20: ./grants_linuxpg.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Did someone already had this error? What do I wrong? I just can't believe that there is a syntax failure in the original script downloaded from the geoportal sourceforge website?!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fix just in case you need it. As sudoer user:

```
sudo gedit grants_linuxpg.sh
```

1) #!/bin/sh -> #!/bin/bash

2) ./createuser -> createuser

3) ./psql -> psql

4) sudo gedit grants_pg.txt -> #sudo gedit grants_pg.txt